# Google Analytics: Invalid Credentials, Google_service_exception error?

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

**UPDATE**: I've tried generating a new client secret, and uploading that new json file to be read from for the necessary credentials, and it still doesn't work.

I used to have fully functional code but upon injecting some HTML into an echo statement in the PHP file, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}' in /home/myprojusername/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /home/myprojusername/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 /home/myprojusername/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /home/myprojusername/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() #4 /home/myprojusername/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(779): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Guzzle in /home/myprojusername/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

My code is pretty simple, and I obtained it through the Google Analytics API PHP quickstart.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php

Here's my 'index.php':

```
<?php
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('../config/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    // Set the access token on the client.
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    // Create an authorized analytics service object.
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

    // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.
    $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    printResults($results);

} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {
    // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

    // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $properties->getItems();
            $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

            // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
            ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();

                // Return the first view (profile) ID.
                return $items[0]->getId();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
}

function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
    // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
    // for the last seven days.
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '7daysAgo',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults(&$results) {
    // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
    // the profile name and total sessions.
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
        print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";
    } else {
        print "<p>No results found.</p>";
    }
}
```

My 'oauth2callback.php':

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('../config/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Like I said, this code was operational, but after putting some "echo '......'; " into the php code, it stopped working.

Does Google see any useless code injection as a threat and then block any reading access to your app if this happens?

Comment: I don't see any  "echo '......';" in your code but I would suggest you remove them.  Invalid Credentials means that the client id or client secret is incorrect. Google cant find your project.

Comment: @DaImTo I removed the echo statements, I just requested a new client secret and uploaded/currently using. Still the same error persists.